# Как закачать файл на сервер с php ?

Tags: php

Может кто дать пример на php, как закачать файл на сервер со статусбаром (можно и без него).

Answer (score 2):

Для статус бара нужет JQuery плагин Uploadify, погуглите, сами найдете мануал, как поставить их в сети вагоны. Без прогресбара

1. Делаем форму form.html
2. Делаем файл загрузчик upload.php

form.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input name="file" type="file"> <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

upload.php

```
$folder='/files/';  
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$folder.$filename);
```

Проверки самостоятельно допишете. Файл будет загружен в папку files в корне вебсервера. Если файл не загрузился, значит нужно папки выставить права на запись 777.

Answer (score 0):

Со статусбаром не получиться, для этого надо использовать ajax и т.д. Для закачки файла на сервер средствами php надо использовать $_FILES